# preventing call viewDidLoad twice

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking, nsxmlparser

I have scenario which fetching json requests from API and parse it on view. But if API pushes xml link, i need to start xml parse task with AFNetworking. After parsing xml, i am passing xml as parameter(NSData) in to another class method which i am assigning child values with NSXMLParser, after parsing has finished :

```
-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{

    ViewController *VS = [[VC alloc] init];

    [VC vastXMLReturn:vastXMLDictionary rollType:rollType];
}
```

After  sending parameters in ViewController following method is responsible to play video;

```
-(void)vastXMLReturn:(NSDictionary *)xml rollType:(NSString *)roll
{
    NSLog(@"XML responses = %@",xml);

    //NSString *mediaDuration = [xml objectForKey:@"mediaDuration"];

    NSString *mediaFilePath = [xml objectForKey:@"mediaFilePath"];

    //NSArray *trackingLists = [xml objectForKey:@"trackingLinks"];

    advertisementURL = [NSURL URLWithString:roll];

    [self playVideo:advertisementURL initial_time:0];

}
```

In PlayVideo Method

```
-(void)playVideo:(NSURL *)videoURL initial_time:(NSTimeInterval)playerTime
{
    theMoviPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];


    theMoviPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

    [self performSelector:@selector(closeButtonForVideoPlayer) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];

    theMoviPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

    theMoviPlayer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(theMoviPlayer.view.transform, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2));

    [self.view addSubview:theMoviPlayer.view];

    //[theMoviPlayer.moviePlayer requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:@[ @4.3f ] timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];

    [theMoviPlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

}
```

The real problem is after [theMoviPlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES]; line, breakpoint jumps in viewDidLoad method which is should not happen because the process will be starting in that method again and program terminates error.

What should i have to do for preventing goes in viewDidLoad method ?

Best Regards

Comment: viewDidLoad shouldn't be called twice unless you're loading the UIViewController unexpectedly. fullScreen property of MPMoviePlayerController causes the movie player to enter or exit full-screen mode. I suspect you are doing something else which causes the mentioned behaviour.

Comment: I checked all methods and made debugging. Just i am suspecting is NSXMLParser  using GDC  that's why it calls ViewController more than once ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with GCD.

Comment: can you post your viewDidLoad method?